# Устройство defer в golang

Tags: golang

Есть следующий кусок кода:

```
   func f1() int {
        var x int
        defer func() { 
            x+=90
        }()
        x = 1
        return x 
    }
```

Функция f1 всегда будет возвращать 1.

Есть другая функция:

```
func f2() (x int) {
    defer func() { 
        x+=90
    }()
    x = 1
    return
}
```

Функция f2 всегда будет возвращать 91.

Почему они так работают? Нигде информации не могу найти, которые бы навели меня на что грешить: на устройство работы defer или же устройство работы с переменными или и то и то.

Comment: defer выполняется по выходы с блока. В первом случае на этот момент значение уже скопировано и меняется только локальная переменная, которая будет скоро удалена. в втором случае меняется переменная, которая объявлена в "более наружном блоке ". Хотя соглашусь, с первого взгляда супернеочевидно.

Answer (score 1):

В ваших примерах отложенная функция использует переменную `x` из внешнего окружения. Когда компилятор ищет кандидата на добавление в замыкание, он просматривает код вверх по тексту, до первого символа с именем `x`, видимого в точке определения отложенной функции.

В первом примере

```
   func f1() int {
        var x int
        defer func() { 
            x+=90
        }()
```

первый встреченный символ `x` связан с внутренней переменной. Отложенная функция эту переменную обновит, но на результат это уже не повлияет, так как результат записан в стек, и (**внимание**) адрес области стека с возвращаемым значением не равен области, отведённой для внутренней переменной `x`.

Во втором примере

```
func f2() (x int) {
    defer func() { 
        x+=90
    }()
```

компилятор свяжет символ `x` внутри отложенной функции с символом `x`, обозначающим возвращаемое значение функции. Поэтому результат вычисления выражения `x+=90` будет записан как раз в ту область стека, где хранится возвращаемое значение.